# Clicking Tableview Cell Does Not Display Data

Tags: json, swift, database, uitableview

I'm having trouble with my `didSelectRowAt` function of my tableview. For some reason, although my segue identifier and destination view are correct, when I click the row, it does not load anything. Furthermore, Xcode informs me:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Double?' to type 'String?'

but I cannot find an online resource that tells me how to resolve this. For reference, the data I would like to display is from a nested JSON feed.

**JSON Struct**

```
struct PlayerStatsParent:Decodable{
    let rankings: [PlayerStats]
}

struct PlayerStats:Decodable {
    let personaname: String?
    let score: Double?
    let solo_competitive_rank: Int?
    let avatar: String?
}
```

**Cell Select Function**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? RankDetail {
        destination.playerRank = rank[(rankTable.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
    }
}
```

**Destination View Controller Code**

```
import UIKit

class RankDetail: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var rankLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    var playerRank:PlayerStats?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        rankLabel.text = "\(playerRank?.solo_competitive_rank)"
        scoreLabel.text = playerRank?.score
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also check your select method.Should be this.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

Not this;

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
```

}

If you select the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error occurs in the `RankDetail` class.
Here's a simple fix.

```swift
class RankDetail: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var rankLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    var playerRank:PlayerStats?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        rankLabel.text = "\(playerRank?.solo_competitive_rank)"
        // scoreLabel.text if of type String?, so it can't store Double? directly
        // scoreLabel.text = playerRank?.score
        // converting to String? should fix it
        scoreLabel.text = "\(playerRank?.score)"
}
```

EDIT:
Present `ViewController` using the following code. Saves you the trouble of having to worry about segues.

```swift
if let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewViewController") {
      present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

Comment: I no longer get an error, but the cells do not load data when clicked. This leads me to believe something went wrong when creating the playerRank variable, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: So the `segue` occurs but you don't see any data in the new `ViewController`?

Comment: actually, no segue occurs. Basically, when I click a cell the cell takes me nowhere, and if I click another cell the app crashes. Could it be that the segue is trying to load, but it can't?

Comment: Yes, I think we can safely narrow it down to the segue. Perhaps the name is mistyped or it isn't properly connected. There's another way to navigate to a ViewController, refer to my edit.